# I am getting DDoS attack continuously from last 20 days

Tags: security, server, ddos

I am getting DDoS attack continuously since 20 days, tried almost everything, disabling and enabling plugins and all. Its not getting stopped. Need help.

security

Comment: This needs additional information.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I am getting false traffic on a blank page which doesn't even exits on my website, Got to know that its DDoS attack happening, so tried almost everything to protect my site but not able to stop the attack.  tried some plugins but Its still happening. my website is just 6 months old but still got attacked this bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Cloudflare in order to protect against DDoS Layer 7 attacks for Layer 4 attacks I would recommend using an other provider for example OVH or any provider with good DDoS protection then you should be safe.

Also plugins won't help you much against an DDoS attack.